# POST Request with Cookies | Python > PHP

Tags: php, python

Having trouble transforming this python code into PHP, it doesn't seem like the PHP version sends the cookie.

Python:

```
      jar = r.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
      jar.set('.ROBLOSECURITY', cookie, domain='.roblox.com', path='/')
      resp = r.post(url="https://auth.roblox.com/v2/logout", cookies=jar)
      print (resp.content)
```

My attempt at making it PHP:

```
      $ch = curl_init("https://auth.roblox.com/v2/logout");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array()));
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, ".ROBLOSECURITY=" . $cookie);
      $resp = curl_exec($ch);
      print_r ($resp);
```

PHP Output:

```
    HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Pragma: no-cache
    Content-Length: 83
    Content-Type: application/json
    Expires: -1
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    Roblox-Machine-Id: RP-WEB1004
    P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM 
    PRE"
    Date: Sat, 27 Oct 2018 14:29:39 GMT


{"errors":[{"code":0,"message":"Authorization has been denied for this 
request."}]}
```

Comment: It's odd for a JSON API  to require a cookie,  but it looks ok at first glance to me.  Any reason why you're posting to a logout resource and any information from the API as to what else can cause a 401?  Also, even though you're not actually passing any json data, you failed to set the content-type to json.

Comment: Posting to a logout resource to obtain an X-CSRF-TOKEN, the python code works correctly, but the PHP one doesn't. I'll try with the content type and let you know how it goes.